# Spring, контроллер GET, разбор входящих параметров

Tags: spring

Есть контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkunitpay", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public
@ResponseBody
String checkunitpay(String method, String params){
...
}
```

Вызывается это так

http://localhost/pay/checkunitpay?method=check&params%5Baccount%5D=1&params%5Bdate%5D=2015-12-01%2015%3A14%3A00&params%5Boperator%5D=mts&params%5BorderCurrency%5D=RUB&params%5BorderSum%5D=10.00&params%5BpaymentType%5D=webmoney&params%5Bprofit%5D=9.5&params%5BprojectId%5D=24950&params%5Bpurse%5D=R123456789123&params%5Bsign%5D=4ac55e5a74c34fe1b6c5fd9473b76419&params%5Bsum%5D=10&params%5BunitpayId%5D=37418

Или вот

```
 method=check 
 params[account]=user12 
 params[date]=2012-10-01 12:32:00 
 params[operator]=beeline 
 params[paymentType]=mc 
 params[projectId]=1 
 params[phone]=9XXXXXXXXX 
 params[sum]=10.00 
 params[sign]=9bdf52a4830779a1383ac24f1b3ed054 
 params[orderSum]=10.00 
 params[orderCurrency]=RUB 
 params[unitpayId]=1234567
```

Так вот как такой запрос обработать в контролере ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом плане Spring достаточно гибкий.
Можете использовать старый проверенный способ (при большом числе параметров он удобный):

```
@ResponseBody
String checkunitpay(HttpServletRequest request){
    Map params = request.getParameterMap();
    //Достаем параметры, валидируем, обрабатываем...
}
```

Так же ещё есть аннотация `@RequestParam`, рекомендую поглядеть, но тогда будет нагромождение в параметрах.